# Pointer of a struct with vector - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, pointers, vector, struct

Why can't I assign a value to `qtd_lines` ?

```
typedef struct{
  int x;
  int y;
  char z;
}struct_c;

typedef struct{
   int qtd_lines;
   struct_c *vector;
}struct_a;

int main(){
 struct_a *pointer;

//This gives me Segmentation Fault.
 pointer->qtd_lines = 10;
 pointer->vetor = (struct_c *)  malloc(pointer->qtd_lines * sizeof(struct_contas));

 return 0;
}
```

Ok, I have a vector in my `struct_c`, but the field `qtd_lines` is not a vector, right ? So Why am I getting this error ?

Comment: `pointer` is uninitialize.

Comment: Come on, this is really basic.  Pointers have to point somewhere before you can use them.

Comment: @MattMcNabb My vector points to another struct, every vector is a pointer. OK. But do I have to point somewhere to use the `qtd_lines` ? It's just an integer.

Comment: *pointer is not pointing anywhere*. There is no integer. There is no `pointer->qtd_lines`, until you make `pointer` point to some allocated memory. This is nothing to do with `vector`.

Comment: In case you are unaware, you do not need to use dynamic allocation; you can write `struct_a foo; foo.qtd_lines = 10; foo.vector = malloc....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers store memory addresses **only**.

```
struct_a *pointer;
```

This just declares a variable that holds some memory address. At that memory address there *might* be a `struct_a` object, or there might *not* be.

Then how do you know whether `pointer` points to an actual object or not? You have to assign a memory address to the pointer.

---

You can either dynamically allocate a block of memory to hold the object, and assign the address of that memory to `pointer`:

```
pointer = malloc(sizeof(struct_a));
```

Or you can allocate the object on the stack, and then store the memory address of that object in the pointer:

```
struct_a foo;
pointer = &foo;
```

---

But as it stands, in your code `pointer` doesn't point to anything, but you use the `->` operator to access the memory that the pointer points to.

And in C you actually **can** do that, but you get undefined behavior. Like a segmentation fault. Or possibly just weird behavior. Anything is possible.

So, just make the pointer point to something before using it.

Answer (score 1):

`pointer->qtd_lines = 10;` is writing at unallocated location. You need to initialize `pointer`.

```
 struct_a *pointer = malloc(struct_a);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case only structure pointer is declared. No memory is allocated for that.

Assign this like so:

```
struct_a* pointer = (struct_a*)malloc(sizeof(struct_a));
```

Also once you done your things please don't forget to free that memory since it was taken from the Heap memory segment.

```
free(pointer);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: even if using your phone to code, please remember indenting your code correctly to mark it as such, and also not to let EVERY line start with an uppercase letter, the function is called `free`, not `Free` ;)